# mqtt-Where mosquitto store all topics?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I’m tracing mosquitto for a few days
I want to check some questions:

1. Would MQTT broker store all of the pub/sub topics when they pub/sub? if yes,where?
2. Which struct(or file?) when publish send a message, publisher will search the struct whether topic has been used,and then reused it?

Thank you all for answer for mqtt  beginner.

Comment: Have you already looked at the mosquitto source code? The file names are pretty descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Short answers:

To keep it simple lets assume QOS 0

1. No, the broker only needs to keep a list of which topics/topic patterns each client is subscribed to. There is no need to keep any information about a published message under unless it needs to queue that message for a offline client with a persistent subscription or it's a retained message.
2. Your second question doesn't really make any sense, but I assume you mean which structure does the broker search when it receives a new message from a publisher. In which case I suggest you look at the very aptly named [handle_publish.c](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/src/handle_publish.c)